# ofStream error: writing to text file?

Tags: c++, file, io, output, ofstream

So I have this function that writes to a text file but I keep getting this error that has something to do with the syntax of outputting using ofstream I believe.
Can someone help diagnose this for me?

Thanks,

Evin

```
int writeSave(string chName, string chSex, string chRace, 
              vector<int> chAttributes, int chLevel, int chStage)
{
    ofstream outputFile("saveFile.txt");
    outputFile << "chName: " << chName <<
                  "\nchSex: " << chSex <<
                  "\nchRace: " << chRace <<
                  "\nchAttributes: " << chAttributes <<
                  "\nchLevel: " << chLevel <<
                  "\nchStage: " << chStage;
    return 0;
}
```

Running /home/ubuntu/workspace/saveGame/sgFunc.cpp

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/saveGame/sgFunc.cpp: In function ‘int writeSave(std::string, std::string, std::string, std::vector<int>, int, int)’: /home/ubuntu/workspace/saveGame/sgFunc.cpp:27:44: error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
                     "\nchRace: " << chRace <<
                                            ^

In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39:0,
                 from /home/ubuntu/workspace/saveGame/sgFunc.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:602:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = std::vector<int>]’
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
     ^
```

Comment: Unless you've redefined the `<<` operator for `vectors` you cannot simply do `<< chAttributes`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector<>` can't be streamed (by default) to a character output stream, which is what you are trying to do with `<< chAttributes`.  You need to manually convert it to a string, or provide an `operator<<` for streaming it to a character output stream.

One option, if you want to write out the contents comma-delimited (you need to include `<iterator>` and `<algorithm>`):

```
outputFile << "chName: " << chName <<
              "\nchSex: " << chSex <<
              "\nchRace: " << chRace <<
              "\nchAttributes: ";

copy(chAttributes.begin(),
     chAttributes.end(),
     ostream_iterator<int>(outputFile, ","));

outputFile << "\nchLevel: " << chLevel <<
              "\nchStage: " << chStage;
```

---

I wrote this example code assuming `using namespace std;` as your code appears to.  I would advise against using this line, and instead `std::`-qualify stuff you want to use from the `std` namespace.